# Query Importrange with concat - adding 2 of the returned columns together

Tags: import, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I am trying to import specified data using query importrange but at the same time I want to reduce need for additional calculation columns and by using concat or something similar to add 2 columns together with a space in between ie. first name 'bob' last name 'smith' returns 'bob smith' in 1 column

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oaZP3-p1cI4d1QyLQ2qM5sMwnVGz8S0bhe29W4QqH6g/edit#gid=1908577977","Sheet7!A2:c"),"select Col1&" "&Col2,Col3",0})
```

I've tried the above but it returns formula parse error

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oaZP3-p1cI4d1QyLQ2qM5sMwnVGz8S0bhe29W4QqH6g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in post-IMPORTRANGE you can join two columns only like this:

```
=FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("13Ptmj3sejlOADvwhgfBPxRy_H-RGCxLX4r2jecbceIE", "Sheet7!A2:C"), 
 "select Col1,Col2", )),,9^9))
```

so for 3 columns:

```
={FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("13Ptmj3sejlOADvwhgfBPxRy_H-RGCxLX4r2jecbceIE", "Sheet7!A2:C"), 
 "select Col1,Col2", )),,9^9)), 
 IMPORTRANGE("13Ptmj3sejlOADvwhgfBPxRy_H-RGCxLX4r2jecbceIE", "Sheet7!C2:C")}
```

Comment: Another cool formula @player0 thank you